# How can I solve this wrong behaviour in gf command?

Tags: filetype-python, navigation

For some reason, on a specific project I work on (no per project configuration on my side). The gf command does a replacement of the last dot to slash, as if I'm in a Java file, even though it is a python file type.

Meaning a gf in the following line:

```python
sql = "a/path/to/a/file.sql"
```

Results in the following error:

```
E447: Can't find file "a/path/to/a/file/sql" in path
```

By reading the `includeexpr` help I saw that maybe its doing something funky to the gf input, but this is the `includeexpr` in my vim runtime (never changed it from whatever default, probably associated with the `filetype=python`)

```
includeexpr=substitute(substitute(substitute(v:fname,b:grandparent_match,b:grandparent_sub,''),b:parent_match,b:parent_sub,''),b:child_match,b:child_sub,'g')
```

I don't see any substitution of `.` for `/` going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now the problem wasn't the substitute command in `includeexpr`. The call to `includeexpr` is a behavior for when the search path isn't found in the file tree. As per the help on `gf`:

```
If the file can't be found, 'includeexpr' is used to
modify the name and another attempt is done.
```

So the problem was that my path was set to the `**` glob pattern for downward search in the filetree.

To do so, I added in my vimrc:

```
set path+=**
```

Or in Lua:

```
vim.opt.path:append '**'
```

Comment: Yeah, if you don’t need this i dont recommend it: https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy

Comment: We are glad that you found the cause but what was the solution? Did you simply remove the offending line or did you do something smarter? [FWIW…](https://gist.github.com/romainl/7e2b425a1706cd85f04a0bd8b3898805).

Comment: I would say it wasn't an error, in and of it self. The error mentioned in my questioning was in the default behavior after not finding the file in the path.